# How can I get public URL from MiniO object to preview it in browser, not automatically download it?

Tags: node.js, minio

I am working with MiniO and NodeJS. Now I have to return the URL of an object, but that URL must preview the object not download it? The bucket policy is set to public and download.

This is the example link it always downloads the object and does not preview it:

http://minio-img-server-dtp-dsa-dev.vsan-apps.playcourt.id/laporan/laporan_198e8f00-6a81-11ea-9614-5b99d8c76683.png